# Project with path 'x' could not be found in project 'y' when using flavor implementation

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android library with flavors defined

```
flavorDimensions "player"

productFlavors {
    educator {
      dimension "player"
    }
    learner {
      dimension "player"
    }
  }
```

and dependencies like so

```
dependencies {
    learnerImplementation project(':learnerFeatureModule')
}
```

Now when I use this library in my Educator app, I get error

```
Project with path ':learnerFeatureModule' could not be found in project ':myLibrary'
```

because I have not defined `:learnerFeatureModule` in my `settings.gradle`.

I have defined missing strategy in Educator `app/build.gralde` too.

```
missingDimensionStrategy 'player', 'educator'
```

But `learnerFeatureModule` is learnerImplementation. Why is educator app even trying to resolve this?

I need a way, where Educator app does not look for this module as its not requried.

Answer (score 0):

1 workaround that solves it for me (this does not use flavor as such)

in library build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    def skipLearnerModule = rootProject.ext.get("skipLearnerModule")
    if(!skipLearnerModule)
        implementation project(':learnerFeatureModule')
```

and in educator app's root build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        skipLearnerModule = true
    }
```

I believe the reason why flavor does not work is because gradle's project configure step tries to resolve module for all variant of the app